# Uncaught TypeError: this._queue[1] is not a function

Tags: javascript, famous-engine

My index.js looks like this

```
'use strict';

// Famous dependencies
var DOMElement = require('famous/dom-renderables/DOMElement');
var FamousEngine = require('famous/core/FamousEngine');
var CustomNode = require('./CustomNode');
var Animation = require('./components/Animation');
// Boilerplate code to make your life easier
FamousEngine.init();

var scene = FamousEngine.createScene('body');
var rootNode = scene.addChild();

var plane = rootNode.addChild(new CustomNode('url(images/plane_100x100.png)', '#B3E5FC', 200, 200, 100, 100));
var animation = new Animation(plane);
animation.start();
```

where CustomNode.js is

```
var DOMElement = require('famous/dom-renderables/DOMElement');
var FamousEngine = require('famous/core/FamousEngine');
var Transitionable = require('famous/transitions/Transitionable');
var Size = require('famous/components/Size');
var Node = require('famous/core/Node');
function CustomNode(bgUrl, bgColor, xpos, ypos, width, height) {
  Node.call(this);
  this.setSizeMode('absolute', 'absolute')
          .setAbsoluteSize(width, height)
          .setPosition(xpos,ypos);
  this.nodeDomElement = new DOMElement(this);
  this.nodeDomElement.setProperty('backgroundImage', bgUrl);
  this.nodeDomElement.setProperty('zIndex', '2');
  this.nodeDomElement.setProperty('background-color', bgColor);
}
CustomNode.prototype = Object.create(Node.prototype);
CustomNode.prototype.constructor = CustomNode;
module.exports = CustomNode;
```

And Animation.js looks like this

```
var FamousEngine = require('famous/core/FamousEngine');
var Transitionable = require('famous/transitions/Transitionable');

// A component that will animate a node's position in x.
function Animation (node) {
    // store a reference to the node
    this.node = node;
    // get an id from the node so that we can update
    this.id = node.addComponent(this);
    // create a new transitionable to drive the animation
    this.xPosition = new Transitionable(100);
}

Animation.prototype.start = function start () {
    // request an update to start the animation
    this.node.requestUpdate(this.id);
    // begin driving the animation
    this.xPosition.from(100).to(1000, {duration: 1000});
    this.node.requestUpdate(this.id);
};

Animation.prototype.onUpdate = function onUpdate () {
    // while the transitionable is still transitioning
    // keep requesting updates
    if (this.xPosition.isActive()) {
        // set the position of the component's node
        // every frame to the value of the transitionable
        this.node.setPosition(this.xPosition.get());
        this.node.requestUpdateOnNextTick(this.id);
    }
};
module.exports = Animation;
```

But when I run famous dev, I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._queue[1] is not a function
```

Please note that I am working off of the develop branch of famous/engine

This code is posted on github

https://github.com/codesdk/famous_engine_issue_debug_animation

for easy cloning

Please use the instructions in the README

Comment: What line does the error point on?

Comment: This is what I'm getting on the console...no src filename in the error Uncaught TypeError: this._queue[1] is not a functionget @ bundle.js:10794onUpdate @ bundle.js:13621update @ bundle.js:3521_update @ bundle.js:2036step @ bundle.js:2174handleFrame @ bundle.js:2156handleMessage @ bundle.js:2107_channel.onMessage @ bundle.js:1957postMessage @ bundle.js:1125update @ bundle.js:10109step @ bundle.js:9060loop @ bundle.js:9076_looper @ bundle.js:8889

Comment: Can you post your project to GitHub so we can have the whole projet and run it?

Comment: Posted https://github.com/codesdk/famous_engine_issue_debug_animation

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to pass the correct arguments into Transitionable#to:

```
this.xPosition.from(100).to(1000, 'linear', 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have mixed up the `set` and `to` methods of `Transitionable`.

```js
this.xPosition.from(100).to(1000, {duration: 1000});
```

Should be:

```js
    this.xPosition.from(100).to(1000, 'linear', 1000);
```

```js
Animation.prototype.start = function start () {
    // request an update to start the animation
    this.node.requestUpdate(this.id);
    // begin driving the animation
    this.xPosition.from(100).to(1000, 'linear', 1000);
    this.node.requestUpdate(this.id);
};
```

Remember that `setPosition` of a node takes all three axis `setPosition(x,y,z)`

```js
Animation.prototype.onUpdate = function onUpdate () {
    // while the transitionable is still transitioning
    // keep requesting updates
    if (this.xPosition.isActive()) {
        // set the position of the component's node
        // every frame to the value of the transitionable
        this.node.setPosition(this.xPosition.get(), 0, 0);
        this.node.requestUpdateOnNextTick(this.id);
    }
};
```